# Spark Streaming Window width and slide

Tags: apache-spark, window, streaming, apache-kafka

I wanted to use spark streaming to process events from kafka and want to set the window width and slide in terms of the number of messages instead of time. Is this possible? I didn't see anything obvious in the api for this and instead only saw time based window options.

Comment: Duplicate question. Please, see [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711439/spark-streaming-scala-window-length-by-number-of-objects/36711807#36711807) for details.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can only set window duration.

Answer (score 0):

This gets near enough to what I would want:
[Output an event based on a number of messages within a specific time period]
https://damieng.com/blog/2015/06/27/time-window-events-with-apache-spark-streaming